# Why added node in SpriteKit does not fit the window?

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

My goal is to add a node which will have sizes equal to the sizes of the window in which the node is presenting.

When I'm trying this:

```
var screenSize: NSSize!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    screen = self.view?.frame.size

    addCanvasNode()
}

fileprivate func addCanvasNode() {
    canvasNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: -screen.width / 2, y: -screen.height / 2, width: screen.width, height: screen.height))
    canvasNode.fillColor = .brown
    addChild(canvasNode)
}
```

I get this look:

[image]

I do not get why I have those black borders around my node? Why the width and height of my node do not fit the window sizes? What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because it only fits your `SKView`. You have to configure your `SKView` to fill the whole window.

Comment: Yes but for this i need more information from you. Where do you create your SKView?

Comment: In my `ViewController`. It's boilerplate code generated when you create a new project

Comment: Yes. But this dont help you because the scene is inside the SKView.

Comment: Okay good to know that you create the SKView programmatically. So when you initialize your SKView, set the frame of the SKView to the frame of your window

Comment: Sry i am actually wrong. I dont have a mac right now , but the View is *inside a SKScene* ... so when you create the scene like `var myScene  = SKScene(size: window.size)`

Comment: I cannot do that =/ I cannot get my window properties. `view.window` is always `nil`. OSX is so complicated!

Comment: So to get the window size: `window.frame.size`

Comment: I took it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205180/resizing-the-window-according-to-a-variable-swift

Comment: So dont use the `view` paramerter from your `didMove(to view: SKView)` because it isnt the window. You need get the size of your window

Comment: To handle Windows here a nice Tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/613-windows-and-windowcontroller-tutorial-for-macos